# My returned value is not the same as the one inside function scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

### Issue description:

Hey I ran into a super weird issue I've never previously ran across.

```
// In the code example below you can see the actual functions called
// here is just a pseudo-code for better issue understanding

const checkErrors = (input) => {
  const data = invokeCheckFunction(input)
  console.log('wtf ==>', data) // [{ foo: 'bar'}]
  return data
}
```

and then in a function that just calls it

```
const test = checkErrors(myInput)
console.log('why is it empty', test) // []
```

The only effect in my wrapper function (second code block) - is a `useState` so I'm super baffled as to what could be causing this desync out of nowhere - never ran into a similar issue. Anyone got any idea what could be the culprit?

Here's the (relevant excerpt) of the actual code:

### Error checking:

Error check internal handler:

```
import type { CheckFunction, Config, FieldError } from '../types'

type ErrorWithInternal<T, E = Error> = {
  INTENRAL_IS_ERROR: true
} & FieldError<T, E>

export const invokeCheckFunction = <T, C extends CheckFunction<T>, E = Error>(
  value: T,
  name: string,
  checkFunction: C,
) => {
  let result: ReturnType<C> | ErrorWithInternal<T, E>
  try {
    result = checkFunction(value)
  } catch (error) {
    const fieldError: ErrorWithInternal<T, E> = {
      error: error as E,
      message: (error as Error)?.message,
      name,
      value,
      INTENRAL_IS_ERROR: true,
    }
    result = fieldError
  }
  return result
}
```

and the main handler:

```
const isError = <T, C extends CheckFunction<T>, E = Error>(
  error: ErrorWithInternal<T, E> | ReturnType<C>,
): error is ErrorWithInternal<T, E> => !!(error as ErrorWithInternal<T, E>)?.INTENRAL_IS_ERROR

const isPassed = <T, C extends CheckFunction<T>, E = Error>(
  error: ErrorWithInternal<T, E> | ReturnType<C>,
): error is ReturnType<C> => !isError(error)

export const checkErrors = <T, C extends CheckFunction<T>, E = Error>(
  value: T,
  name: string,
  checkFunctions: C[],
): [FieldError<T, E>[], ReturnType<C>[]] => {
  const results = checkFunctions.map((checkfn) =>
    invokeCheckFunction<T, C, E>(value, name, checkfn),
  )

  const internalErrors: ErrorWithInternal<T, E>[] = results.filter((e) => isError(e))
  const passed = results.filter((e) => isPassed(e)) as ReturnType<C>[]
  const errors: FieldError<T, E>[] = internalErrors.map((e) => {
    // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
    const { INTENRAL_IS_ERROR, ...rest } = e
    return rest as FieldError<T, E>
  })

  console.log('wtf => ', errors, passed)
  return [errors, passed]
}
```

### The hook logic (where the issue happens)

```
export const useField = <T, E = Error, C extends CheckFunction<T> = CheckFunction<T>>(
  name: string,
  initialValue: T,
  configOrCheckFunction?: C | Partial<Config>,
  ...checkFunctions: C[]
) => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState<T>(initialValue)
  // Note: not a useState, not to get confused due to similar syntax
  const [initialErrors, initialCheckResults] = checkErrors<T, C, E>(value, name, checks, config)
  const [errors, setErrors] = useState<FieldError<T, E>[]>(initialErrors)
  const [checkResults, setCheckResults] = useState(initialCheckResults)

  const onChange = (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value: newVal } = event.target
    const [newErrors, newChecked] = checkErrors<T, C, E>(
        newVal as T,
        name,
        checkFunctions,
    )
    console.log('why is it empty', newErrors)
    setErrors(newErrors)
    setValue(newVal)
  }
}
```

Now I omitted some unnecessary parts for the sake of readability, but this is pretty much what it all comes down to and I have no clue what could be causing this as I never ever encountered this sort of behaviour before.

For the sake of complete reproduction, you can find the repository I'm talking about here

> https://github.com/samuelhulla/eformless/tree/master/src

Two most relevant files will be

- `helpers/errorChecking.ts` - The first block
- `useField.ts` - The second block

Then I just used a simple react (vite) app with input for testing i.e.

```
import { useField } from 'eformless'

const App = () => {
  // Example of error handler
  const nonEmpty = (val: string) => {
    if (val.length === 0) {
      throw new Error('Cannot be empty')
    }
    return val
  }

  const test = useField('example', '', nonEmpty)

  return (
    <input name={test.name} value={test.value} onChange={test.onChange} />
  )
}
```

[image]

Comment: What exactly does the actual "check function" involved look like?

Comment: @Pointy It's included inside the question. I've edited the names even in the initial pseudo-code so it's more clear. "check" is `checkErrors` which is being called by the `useField` hook. Specifically from the return of `useField` object's method `onChange`

Comment: No it isn't, as far as I can tell. What does the **real** check function look like? What does it do? How does it "check" whatever it checks?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I misunderstood the original question. It's included in the question now alongside the image of the `console.log` from the code. Essentially it can be any function that takes the same argument as the initializer value and throws error.